# Is there a more elegant way to push and return an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I am still figuring out Promises, but while working with them, I've realized it would be nice to reduce an array of fetch objects and put some throttles next to them. While creating my slow querying function, I realized I couldn't think of an elegant way to push onto an array and return that array better than this.

SO. My question is; **Is there a more elegant way of pushing to an array and returning an array in one step in Javascript than this?**

```js
const mQry = q => fetch(q).then(r=>r.json()); // Fetches and returns json
const throttle = t => new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,t)); // adds a promised timeout

const slowQrys = (q,t) => // pass in an array of links, and a number of milliseconds
    Promise.all(q.reduce((r,o)=> // reduce the queries

        // Here's the big issue. Is there any more elegant way
        // to push two elements onto an array and return an array?
        [...r, mQry(...o), throttle(t)]

    ,[]);
```

And before anyone says, I am super aware that splitting out an array could be not efficient, but I'm probably never using more than 10 items, so it's not a super big deal.

Comment: `flatMap`, but the way you’re using `throttle` makes no sense. What’s it supposed to do? (Is running the fetches in parallel intentional?)

Comment: That isn't throttling. Throttling would be preventing the function from excessively  being invoked - that, at least in this code, doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: I'm honestly quite confused by this code. It's hard to follow what is what with one letter variables. But it *seems* like you should just be able to do `r.concat(mQry(...o), throttle(t))` instead of creating a new array and spreading.

Comment: @VLAZ: That does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Ry- it's more "elegant" than spreading and re-creating the array. Although, as I said, I am not sure what this code is supposed to do. My brain refuses to process it, so I just gave up.

Comment: @bronkula Please don’t ignore the question, it’s important. (The spread in `mQry(...o)` doesn’t make sense either if `q` is an array of links, since `mQry` has one parameter and `o` is one link.)

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner and more efficient equivalent of the general operation

```
q.reduce((r, o) =>
    [...r, f(...o), g(t)])
```

uses [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
q.flatMap(o =>
    [f(...o), g(t)])
```

However, in the context of your question, creating a `throttle(t)` next to each fetch operation in a `Promise.all` is *completely and unambiguously wrong*. All of the `setTimeout` timers will be running in parallel and resolve at the same time, so there’s no point in creating more than one. They don’t interact with the fetch operations, either, just delay the overall fulfilment of the promise `slowQrys` returns and muddle the array it resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your intent is to chain your fetch(s), such that two consecutive fetch are mandatorily spaced by at least `t` ms

The chaining is thus

```
Promise.all([fetch, wait]), Promise.all([fetch, wait]), ...
```

The way to write that thus be

```
const slowQrys = (links, t)=>links.reduce((p, link)=>{
    return p.then(_=>{
        return Promise.all([
            fetch(link),
            wait(t)
        ])
    })
}, Promise.resolve())
```

Comment: Not what I was asking, but neat implementation.

Comment: then I (neither) don't understand your goal. Implem as you provided basically launches all your fetchs in parallel + all the associated "throttles" as well (which is not really useful since they don't slow down anything apart the final synchronization of Promise.all). IF your goal is to fetch, wait, fetch wait,..., then use reduce such as construction I provided? (```p.then(_=>fetch(link)).then(_=>wait(t))```)

Comment: I'm not asking how to make the whole thing better. I'm asking if there is a more elegant way to return an array while pushing a new value into it.

Comment: then VLAZ is the way to go, use ```concat```
you can also ```r.push(a,b), r``` using the fact that the value of the expression you return is r (which is a reference to your array)